# How can I extract text from a span tag using beautiful soup 4?

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, scraper

how can I scrape text through span tags using beautful soup?
[scrape faculty members informations](http://www.uoj.ac.ae/ContentBan.aspx?m=15&p=4&sm=4#)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get("http://www.uoj.ac.ae/ContentBan.aspx?m=15&p=4&sm=4")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
for tag in soup.find_all('table'):
    if tag.has_attr("class"):
        if tag['class'] == 'MsoTableGrid':
            for tag1 in soup.findAll('span'):
                print tag1.text
```

I want to print the text inside span tags, but the output i get is:

```
 Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find *`tr` elements of `table` where class `MsoTableGrid`* using CSS selectors, and then get needed information, say, faculty name and email address, from columns of the row, for example  :

```
>>> rows = soup.select("table.MsoTableGrid tr")
>>> for r in rows:
...     faculty_info = r.find_all("td")[1:3]
...     if len(faculty_info) == 2:
...         print faculty_info[0].text.strip(), faculty_info[1].text.strip()
... 
Name E-mail
Dr. Hassan Ali Dabouq dr.hassandbouk@uoj.ac.ae
Prof.dr.Magdie   Medhat Elnahry magdielnahry@uoj.ac.ae
Dr. Abd   Elwahaab Mohamed Khalil abdelwahab@uoj.ac.ae
Dr.   Ahmed Hassan Fouly Dr.ahmedfoly@uoj.ac.ae
Dr.   Walid Mohamed Abbas walidabas@uoj.ac.ae
Dr. Wael   Mahmoud Fakhry wfakhry@uoj.ac.ae
Dr.   Kamel Abd Elaziz Ali kamelali@uoj.ac.ae
.
.
.
```

Comment: How can i store these values in a csv file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract from all the span text irrespective of the class name, then try this:-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get("http://www.uoj.ac.ae/ContentBan.aspx?m=15&p=4&sm=4")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
span_text = soup.findAll('span')
for s in span_text:
    print(s.text)
```